# Is it considered good style to dereference `new` pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, dereference

To avoid keep having to use `->` and instead work directly with the object, is it acceptable  practice to do:

```
obj x = *(new obj(...));
...
delete &obj;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is not just poor practice, but:

1. Leaking memory (most likely, unless you are using some pattern that is not visible from the code you provided), since `obj` will store a *copy* of the original object created by the `new` expression, and the pointer to that object returned by `new` is lost;
2. Most importantly, **undefined behavior**, since you are passing to `delete` a pointer to an object that was not allocated with `new`. Per paragraph 5.3.5/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer 
>   value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression*, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8)
>   representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). **If not, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: And the second trumps the first.  He won't leak memory, because the program probably won't run long enough for him to do more than one allocation.

Comment: Well, one can do `obj &x = *new` at the very least.

Answer (score 9):

No, and in fact this leads to a leak. `x` is **copy initialized**, so the original object pointed to by `new obj` is lost.

Just use

```
obj x(...);
```

No need for dynamic allocation. Or

```
obj x = obj(...);
```

if you must (doubt it).

Comment: Or you could use a reference `obj& = (*new ...`

Comment: @Marcin You could, but why?

Comment: @Marcin yes, you could. You could also smash your keyboard to your screen. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: @JamesKanze Because OP wants to avoid dereferencing all the time, which is what references are for.

Comment: @Marcin You don't have to dereference if you follow Luchian's suggestion.

Comment: @JamesKanze True, but you also have something allocated differently than before. This may not be what OP wants.

Answer (score 7):

Certainly not; that copies the dynamic object to an automatic variable, loses the only pointer to it, and then attempts to delete the automatic copy. You've got a memory leak and an invalid deletion.

Much better would be to use an automatic variable in the first place:

```
obj x(...);
...
// no need to delete anything
```

or, if it really must be dynamic for some reason (because it's too big for the stack, or you don't always want to destroy it here), then use a smart pointer, and a reference if you really don't like `->`

```
std::unique_ptr<obj> p(new obj(...));
obj & x = *p;
...
// still no need to delete anything
```

Changing your `x` into a reference would be valid (as long as you're careful that exceptions, early function returns, etc. won't cause a leak), but would cause howls of confusion among anyone unfortunate enough to have to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete your object properly if you do it like that.

Implicitly you do the following.

```
class A
{
public:
  int test (void) { return 1; }
};

int main (void)
{
  A * p = new A;
  A v(*p);
  //...
  delete &v; // &v != p and v is not constructed via new!
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to work with an object-like-syntax you can bind a reference to the object.

```
class A
{
public:
  int test (void) { return 1; }
};

int main (void)
{
   A * p = new A;
   A & r = *p;
   int i = r.test();
   delete p;
   return 0;
}
```

If you delete your object through the same pointer, there will be no leak.